# TF: Tensor name not found in checkpoint files

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I've been working trying to use the pretrained model given in this repo https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim. I'm using this net https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v3.py and the checkpoint file given in the main page of the repository for ILSVRC-2012-CLS image classification dataset. I'm downloading the one for Inception V3.

I'm just trying to make a prediction so my code is as follow:

```
placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, input_width, input_height, 3])

# Select the model
model = inception(placeholder)

# Predict
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.train.Saver().restore(sess, "./model/inception_v3.ckpt")
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    predictions = sess.run(model, feed_dict={placeholder: input})
```

But I'm receiving an error `"NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Tensor name "InceptionV3/AuxLogits/Conv2d_2a_5x5/biases" not found in checkpoint files ./model/inception_v3.ckpt"`.

So I don't know if the ckpt file is not updated to the Tensor names or if I'm doing something wrong. I've check all Tensor Names in the inception_v3.ckpt file and I weren't able to find the tensor name which give me the error.

Thanks in advance.